# How do I fix an Error whenever my Android AlertDialog loads, the application crashes

Tags: java, android

Hi Guys please recommend a solution for me.
 when preparing an alert dialogue, see the error i get
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.techlinemobile.foodbasket, PID: 22724
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.techlinemobile.foodbasket.ItemDetails.showAddedToCartDialogue(ItemDetails.java:162)
        at com.techlinemobile.foodbasket.ItemDetails.access$300(ItemDetails.java:25)
        at com.techlinemobile.foodbasket.ItemDetails$1.onClick(ItemDetails.java:131)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

see the method

private void showAddedToCartDialogue() {

```
//before inflating the custom alert dialog layout, we will get the current activity viewgroup
ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

//then we will inflate the custom alert dialog xml that we created
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.added_to_cart_dialog, viewGroup, false);

//Now we need an AlertDialog.Builder object
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

//setting the view of the builder to our custom view that we already inflated
builder.setView(dialogView);

//finally creating the alert dialog and displaying it
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
final Button buttonContinue = (Button)alertDialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.buttonContinue);
final Button buttonViewCart = (Button)alertDialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.buttonViewCart);

buttonContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "before adding card");
        //--------------------------------
        //load data to cart
        Intent it = new Intent(ItemDetails.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
});

buttonViewCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "before adding card");
        //--------------------------------
        //load data to cart

        Intent it = new Intent(ItemDetails.this, ShoppingCartActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);


    }
});
alertDialog.show();
```

}

see the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_success" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/added_to_cart"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/successfully_added_long"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonContinue"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="@string/continue_shopping"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonViewCart"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:text="@string/view_cart"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
Button buttonContinue = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonContinue);
Button buttonViewCart = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonViewCart);
```

instead of

```
Button buttonContinue = (Button)alertDialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.buttonContinue);
```

and create dailoge at the end like this.

```
    alertDialog= alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Move the line `alertDialog.show()` to right under `builder.create()`. Or you can use `builder.show()` method which will create and show the dialog immediately.

The error reported that you set listener on null object. Your dialog is not visible so that `findViewById` return null. Variables `buttonContinue` and `buttonViewCart` refer to null value.

```
//before inflating the custom alert dialog layout, we will get the current activity viewgroup
ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

//then we will inflate the custom alert dialog xml that we created
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.added_to_cart_dialog, viewGroup, false);

//Now we need an AlertDialog.Builder object
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

//setting the view of the builder to our custom view that we already inflated
builder.setView(dialogView);

//finally creating the alert dialog and displaying it
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

alertDialog.show(); <---------- show dialog here

final Button buttonContinue = (Button)alertDialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.buttonContinue);
final Button buttonViewCart = (Button)alertDialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.buttonViewCart);

buttonContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "before adding card");
        //--------------------------------
        //load data to cart
        Intent it = new Intent(ItemDetails.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
});

buttonViewCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "before adding card");
        //--------------------------------
        //load data to cart

        Intent it = new Intent(ItemDetails.this, ShoppingCartActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);


    }
});
```